# Laravel: Can't Display Image In Blade File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I tried to display the image in the blade. but it cant load the image, it displays the image of else statement

```
     <?php $user_image_path = 'images/user_images/' . $userDetails['image']; ?>
   
     @if(!empty($userDetails['image']) && file_exists($user_image_path))
          <img src=" {{ asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'])}}" alt="Cinque Terre">
     @else
          <img src="{{ asset('images/product_images/small/no_image.png') }}" alt="Cinque Terre">
     @endif
```

I also debug the code above the if statement it fetches the image

```
 <?php $product_image_path = 'images/user_images/' . $userDetails['image']; ?>
   <?php
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($user_image_path);
   die;
   ?>
```

Comment: Use this code: <img src="{{ url('/images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image']) }}" alt="">

Comment: `file_exists` returns `false` may be. That's why it goes to `else` condition

Comment: yes @A.ANoman it returns false when is remove it then it displays "alt". it also fetches the correct image path "images/user_images/53515".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From above comments on your question, seems like you are loading the image with no extension. add the image extension

```
 <img src="{{  asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'].".png") }}" alt="">
```

or for .jpg

```
<img src="{{  asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image']).".jpg" }}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(!empty($userDetails['image']))
    <img src="{{ asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'])}}" alt="Cinque Terre">
```

- View the src of image inside inspector. Most of the times it gives us the wrong path instead of public directory.
- Secondly, there is space in src. Try to remove and run that.
- If asset function doesn't give the public directory path, add ASSETS_URL In .env to /public

Answer (score 0):

It is the second condition of your if condition that doesn't match. The function of file_exists can't locate the the image file. You either have to provide the full path for the [file_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) , or remove it:

```
@if(!empty($userDetails['image']))
      <img src="{{ asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'])}}" alt="Cinque Terre">
@else
      <img src="{{ asset('images/product_images/small/no_image.png') }}" alt="Cinque Terre">
@endif
```

Comment: then it displays the alt. and in the console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
when I debug the code the image name in the database is fetched correctly also match the image that saves in the user_images folder.
i don't now why this happen

Comment: Where exactly is your image stored? in public folder?

Comment: @MukhlisRaza, in your `src="{{ asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'])}}"`, there is a space at the beginning. I removed it from my answer. please try this time.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
<img src="{{ !empty($userDetails['image']) ? asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image']) : asset('images/product_images/small/no_image.png') }}" alt="Cinque Terre">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<img src=" {{ !empty(asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'])) ? <img src="{{ asset('images/user_images/'.$userDetails['image'])}}" alt="Cinque Terre"> : <img src="{{ asset('images/product_images/small/no_image.png') }}" alt="Cinque Terre"> }}" alt="Cinque Terre">
```